# Why my scss file in vue vite tailwind project stops working as soon as I declare a variable

Tags: vue.js, sass, tailwind-css, vite

My problem happens in a vue project using vite and tailwindcss. I want to use sass thus I do this :

```
npm add -D sass
```

Then I create  a main.scss file under the root of the projec i.e. vue folder.

Inside it I write this.

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;


.test{
    background-color:red;
}
```

In index.html I add

```
  <head>
    ...
    <style lang="sass">
     @import url('./main.scss');
     </style>
  </head>
```

In main.js under vue/src I comment the line importing index.css

```
import {
    createApp} from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
//import './index.css'
import store from "./store";
import router from "./router";
import dayjs from "dayjs";
import 'dayjs/locale/fr';
//dayjs.locale('fr');
import VueCryptojs from "vue-cryptojs";
const app = createApp(App);

app.config.globalProperties.$dayjs = dayjs;

app
    .use(store)
    .use(router)
    .use(VueCryptojs)
    .mount('#app')
```

Then I use the test class in a div of a component. **The background turns red as expected.**

And now comes the problem. If I declare a variable above the test class style declaration in main.scss even without using it,

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

$theVar : rgb(28, 95, 196);


.test{
    background-color: red;
}
```

**The red background is no longer applied** to the div in my component.

What could I do to be able to use variables?

Answer (score 0):

I eventually solved the problem by displacing the style declaration from index.html to App.vue